# How to license a sharepoint solution?

Tags: sharepoint, licensing, web-parts

Let's assume that you've created a SharePoint solution - a WebPart, a feature for a List Template, whatever - that you are planning to sell as a product.

How would you go about handling licensing of your solution?

I'm looking for some input in at least the following areas:

1. Code-wise:

   1.1. Where do you keep the license itself? as a file somewhere? (then what happens in farms?) as a property in the property bag of the farm?

   1.2. Do you implement "home-calling" - where your solution validate the license every now and then against your company's servers?

   1.3. Any other best practice in this area will be welcome...
2. Business wise: How do you license - per user? per server? per instance (in case of WebParts or List Templates)?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you end up in your case? I read the winning answer but it was not that clear to me (my fault). My interest is in web part especially. Thanks.

Comment: I did not implemented the said project, so I didn't need the suggested solution, but it made perfect sense (and was what I was leaning to anyway).
The solution explains that you create a trial/registration Farm solution which adds a page to the Central Admin for managing the licenses. The licenses are kept in the SPFarm's PropertyBag. Each product queries the SPFarm's PropertyBag for the license when needed.
This is a simple, elegant solution.

Comment: thanks for clarification! So if I got it right:
when you publish/sell your Sharepoint Product #1, you also bundle/ship/sell it with such a Farm solution that manages your licenses.
Later on you'come out with your SharePoint Product #2, and you bundle it with the same Farm solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could tell you what we do:

1. We have a separate farm solution that handles trial/registration support for all our products
2. The license is eventually stored in the farm property bag (you have to support multiple servers)
3. We have a page to enter license key under the central admin solution's page
4. We license by front-end, you can know the number of front-end in the farm in code.
5. All products have a product name and the license key is a one-way encryption containing the product name. the trial support solution handles key validation.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Where do you put a validation logic? Do you validate a license on each request?

Answer (score -1):

1.1 You have to put in in the documentation and in the distribution files.

1.2 I would not do that for a sharepoint web part.

1.3 Invest in layout, documentation, support... Not just in the product itself.

2. Nobody will be able to answer that without knowing detailed information about your product, your market, your competitors, the alternatives, etc. Consider [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136106811) if you are serious about pricing.